# Setting DNS when registrar and host is different

Tags: dns, domain-registrar, nameserver

Just to confirm that my assumptions are correct (if not, please let me know where I'm doing wrong):

- My domain refers to `jkwsp.com`
- The registrar where I have registered my domain is `hioxindia.com`
- My domain is hosted at `ixwebhosting.com`

I have access to DNS settings in the registrar as well as in the hosting.

**Setting 1**.- At Registrar DNS Setting:
Name server is already entered by registrar.

- **Q1.1.** If I do `A record` to the IP given to me by the host, will it work?
- **Q1.2.** For subdomain should I make `Cname record` or a new `A record` point to the IP given to me for subdomain by my host?
- **Q1.3.** To access my site as `http://jkwsp.com` and `http://www.jkwsp.com` do I have to make the entry as:
   `*.jkwsp.com to IP` OR `jkwsp.com to IP` and `www.jkwsp.com as Cname`?

**Setting2**.- At Host:

- **Q2.1** Point the NameServers given by host in Registrar NS record and remove all `A record` mentioned under A record at the Registrar?
- **Q2.2** `A record` and subdomain entry is already created by Host. Since NameServer is pointed to Host now setting at host will take effect and `A record` will point to my site?
  And any future change needs to be done At Host Only?

In Both Settings which one should be preferred?

Comment: accepted the answers as it worked but still have contradiction as settings 2 is not known to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It should. Try it and see.
2. For the subdomain, it depends on how your host sets things up. I think it's easiest to have the host also host DNS; that way they can set some of these things up automatically. For my host, it's a separate `A` record, though as long as the IP addresses stay the same, `CNAME` should also work.
3. I would have the bare domain served from an A record and use a CNAME for www.

Comment: Thanks for Answering, i assume these are for Setting-1 At Registrar.

Answer (score 0):

Q1.3: Use an A record for your www. It's slightly more efficient as your nameserver does not get hit twice. If www is a CNAME, the browser/web client will look for www.jkwsp.com and then will have to ask again for the IP address of jkwsp.com.